# PPA 404 error upon apt-get update? (related to php7)

Tags: apt, 15.10, php7

I get a 404 error upon php7 update from url http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php-7.0/ubuntu/dists/wily/main/binary-amd64/Packages

```
Err ppa.launchpad.net wily/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found

Err ppa.launchpad.net wily/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Fetched 10.4 kB in 4s (2,397 B/s)
W: Failed to fetch ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php-7.0/ubuntu/dists/wily/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php-7.0/ubuntu/dists/wily/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Would anyone know what I should do? Is there another/new PPA for php7?

I removed the http before the ppa.* links because I'm not reputable enough to post more than two links. Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I fixed it. I was doing sudo apt-get install mcrypt php-mcrypt7.0 (or something like that), you need to do sudo apt-get install mcrypt php-mcrypt

without the 7.0

the old php 7 ppa doesn't work, you need to use ppa:ondrej/php instead!

Thank you for reading.